# Is there any command like 'dumpbin' for 'UNIX'

Tags: unix, aix

Is there any command on UNIX or AIX which can behave like [dumpbin](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177429?wa=wsignin1.0) (windows exe)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'nm' should do what you are looking for, to grab symbols

http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_nm.htm

ldd might also be useful to get shared objects requirements

Comment: nm command works for binary files but for lib files it is not working... nm *.lib gives following error nm: *.lib: 0654-202 Error while reading object file header .... is there any other command to dump lib file ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ldd to get shared object and nm for symbols.
hexdump can be usefull to display inputs in different format ( hexa, ascii ... )

Answer (score 0):

Try man pages of below commands:

`objdump`
`nm`
`ldd`